# nginx url rewrite rule

Tags: nginx

I have URL like this

```
http://domain/PROD_SHEP_PDF_Downloader/DownloadPdf?favorId=10100018565295&lang=ru
```

I want to rewrite this part **PROD_SHEP_PDF_Downloader** to this **SHEP_PDF_Downloader** so the result will be

```
http://domain/SHEP_PDF_Downloader/DownloadPdf?favorId=10100018565295&lang=ru
```

This rule doesn't work

```
   location /PROD_SHEP_PDF_Downloader/ {
      rewrite ^/PROD_SHEP_PDF_Downloader/(.*)  SHEP_PDF_Downloader/$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:85;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) say that if you just want to change the URI prefix, you can use this:

```
location /name/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
}
```